# Connection Pooling with PostgreSQL and AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Having a microservices architecture, multiple services speak to my PostgresSQL database. If I now want to deploy parts of my application as AWS Lambda functions, how can I avoid running out of connections?

Reading a couple of articles [[1](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2014/05/22/on-connection-pooling/)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189162/what-are-advantages-of-using-transaction-pooling-with-pgbouncer)], [[3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/postgres-scalability-what-is-the-impact-of-connection-pooling)] I realized PgBouncer may be a good fit for my microservice architecture.

**Do I need a "microservice" in front of my database? How to set this up with AWS Lambda?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=678029) on AWS developer forum, AWS Lambda try to reuse old process when it's possible, which offers possiblity to use a client connection pooling.

In my opininon, use a dedicated connection pooler in front of your database is always a good idea. With it, you minimize open connection on your database, which can be an resource consumer. You can find more information, for Postgresql, on this [blog post](http://hans.io/blog/2014/02/19/postgresql_connection/)

As far as I am aware, AWS doesn't offer a dedicated service for connection pooling. You can use a dedicated instance for this. For Postgresql, PgBouncer is a good option. It doesn't need a heavly cpu or large amount of memory, but you still prefere a network optimized instance. And be careful, with only on instance of PgBouncer, you introduce a spof in your architecture.

Comment: With all the services they offer and they do not offer a connection pooler as a service... it's a shame.

Comment: Let's hope Aurora Serverless fixes that

Comment: For those reading this, AWS now offers a RDS Proxy - which is sort of like "connection pooler as a service"